# what are python closures good for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I understand the technical definition of python closures: let's make it concrete.

```
def foo(x):
    def bar(y):
        print(x+y)
    return bar
```

In this example `x` will get bound with `bar`. But what are these things actually good for? ie in the toy example above one could have just as easily written

```
def bar(x,y):
    print(x+y)
```

I would like to know the best use cases for using closures instead of, for example, adding extra arguments to a function.

Comment: your example is too trivial to be useful. But imagine that you can define a local function using all the local variables of the parent function without having to pass the parameters. That can be very handy. Like a complex lambda.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most used example of closure is for caching functions with a decorator.

```
def cache_decorator(f):

    cache = {}

    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)

        return cache[args]

    return wrapper

@cache_decorator
def some_function(*args):
    ...
```

This way the `cache` cannot be referenced from anywhere, since you do not want your users to tamper with it.

Comment: In your example: why not create a class then?

Comment: because the question is opinion-based.

Comment: so the answer is "do what you like best?".. i figured there were some uses cases that made closures the definitive solution to some problem.. hence my question

Comment: This is simply the most common use of closure I have seen, it does not mean this cannot be made in another way, nor that it is the best way (but it is a good one). It simply is a good example of closure since this is what you are asking.

Comment: understood - thanks!